Isomorphism between $H_{(s)}$ and $L^2$
Consider the following definition

Here I believe we are identifying $U \in \mathcal{S}' (\mathbb R^n)$ with $u\in S(\mathbb R^n)$ such that the above is true and
$$
U(f)= \int fu 
$$
for all Schwartz functions $f$.  The reason I think we need $u \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is because we are taking a fourier transform. However, this interpretation doesn't seem to work with the following fact from my book:

$H_{s}$ is isomorphic to $L^2$

When I tried to prove that I thought the most obvious way to do so is by looking at the map
\begin{align*}
       \vartheta : H_{(s)} (\mathbb{R} ^n) &  \longrightarrow  L^{2} (\mathbb{R} ^n,\mathbb{C} ) \\ 
       U &  \longmapsto  \hat{u} (\zeta ) (1 +  \left| \zeta  \right| ^{2}) ^{\frac{s}{2}}.
      \end{align*}
By definition, this is well defined. However, I do not believe this to be a bijection as consider any $L^2$ function $g$. Then we would need to show that
$$ \frac{g}{(1+|\zeta|^2)^{s/2}} \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n),$$
which is something that can't be right.
Question: Can someone clarify to me formally what is the definition of $H_{(s)}(\mathbb R^n)$ whilst explaining how it is isomorphic to $L^2$?

Every separable Hilbert space is isomorphic to $\ell^2$. Maybe this is used here?

I don't think we can use it here. The reason is that the argument in my book went $H_{(s)}$ is isomorphic to $L^2$ and therefore it is separable. Regardless of that, I still feel like there is am ambiguity in the definition of $H_{(s)}$

You can define the Fourier support of a tempered distribution $u$ by setting $\hat u(\phi):=u(\hat \phi)$ for every function $\phi\in \mathcal{S}$. It turns out that $\hat u$ is still a tempered distribution and actually the Fourier transform is an isomorphism from the space of tempered distributions into itself. You can find all the details in Grafakos “Classical Fourier analysis”.
Then to define $H_s$ you ask that $\hat u$ is takes the form $\hat u(\phi)=\int f\phi\,dx$ and that the function $f$ is such that $f(\xi)(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}$ is square integrable. So you identify the Fourier transform of $u$ with the function $f$.
Given $g$ in $L^2$, its Fourier transform is still in $L^2$. Define
$$v(\phi)=\int \frac{\hat g}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}}\phi\,d\xi$$ for $\phi\in \mathcal{S}$. You should check that $v$ is a tempered distribution. Now you define $u$ to be the inverse Fourier transform of $v$. Then $u$ is also a tempered distribution and by construction it belongs to $H_s$.

Hi, thank you for the answer. To clarify, whenever we are dealing with this identification, for example in your answer $\hat{u}$ with $f$, do we require in our definition that $f$ be a Schwartz function? The reason I am asking is because one would expect the inverse theorem to hold, and to therefore expect that $u$ is identified with $\hat{f}$ (or something of the sorts), but for which we would need the Fourier transform of $f$ to be defined, so we need some regularity e.g. Schwartz function.  On another note, do you know what isomorphism between $H_s$ and $L_2$ they are talking about here?

No, the function $f$ is not a Schwartz function in general. It’s just a measurable function for which that product is in $L^2$. Can you give the precise reference of the book you are referring to?

I am referring to page 39 of Hans Ringstrom's The Cauchy Problem in General Relativity.
